# Getting the url where the request is redirected from in yii2?

Tags: php, redirect, yii2

Sorry for my English, but what I'm trying to say is explained below.

I have a controller say `ControllerCard` which has an action like this.

```
function actionScanCard()
{
    ...
    $this->redirect('/transaction/redeem');
    ...
}
```

In other controllers, `ControllerTransaction`, I am trying to get that it comes/redirected from `/card/scan-card`

```
function actionRedeem()
{
    $redirectFrom = ????;
    if ($redirectFrom === '/card/scan-card')
    {
        // some actions
    }
    else
        throw new ForbiddenHttpException('Must scan card!');
}
```

How do I get this `$redirectFrom` value with Yii2?

Comment: Why not add some session variable and check its presence later on?

Comment: ... or even a URL query param, eg `/transaction/redeem?from=%2Fcard%2Fscan-card`

Comment: @Bizley I've tried using session, but it's harder to manage session (at least for me :p ). I was trying to keep the session on some url like `/transaction/redeem`, `/transaction/redeem-add-details`. But, session must be destroyed at other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the remember() & previous() methods in yii\helpers\BaseUrl.

```
function actionScanCard()
{
    ...
    \yii\helpers\Url::remember();
    $this->redirect('/transaction/redeem');
    ...
}
```

in TransactionController (or other)

```
function actionRedeem()
{
    $url = \yii\helpers\Url::previous();
    if($url === Url::to('card/scan-card')) {
        // some actions
    } else{}
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to `forget` it? :)

Comment: in such a case you'll have to use: `\yii\helpers\Url::remember($url, $name);` then you can forget it by: `Yii::$app->getSession()->remove($name);`